# Almacenar valores de documentos de una colección en una lista (Android Studio y Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, lista

Tengo en firebase Cloud Firestore una colección de usuarios. Y llevo dias intentando obtener el campo nombre de esos usuarios para introducirlos a una lista. (Que mas tarde mi intencion será añadir la lista a un Recycler View)

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    ArrayList<String> usuariosLista = new ArrayList<>();

        db.collection("usuarios")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    private static final String TAG = "";

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                String nombreDeUsuario = document.getString("nombre");
                                Log.d(TAG, nombreDeUsuario);
                                usuariosLista.add(nombreDeUsuario);
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, usuariosLista.get(0));
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });


        //Log.d(TAG, usuariosLista.get(0));
```

La ultima linea que esta comentada, me da el error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0.
Los log anteriores si me muestran los valores correctos. Estoy empezando en android y firebase y no entiendo mucho, al parecer todo lo que ocurre dentro de ese código no se pueden guardar en listas de fuera. He probado con ArrayList, list, arrays, poniendo la lista estatica, ect. y nada.

Alguien me puede ayudar a obtener una lista con los nombres de los usuarios y poder trabajar con ella en cualquier parte del codigo?? gracias.. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toma esto como referencia yo uso kotlin, pero te puede servir mucho para entender tu problema, también estoy empezando espero ayudarte como me ayudaron a mi.

Lo que pasa es que al obtener los datos estas obteniendo una respuesta asíncrona es decir esto pasa de manera diferida o retardada, Entonces en el momento que se ejecuta la linea que comentas, aun no se ha obtenido el string entonces te salta el error. En cambio lo que ocurre dentro de

```
db.collection("usuarios")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>()
```

no avanza hasta que la respuesta ASINCRONA no haya sido retornada?, por eso " Los log anteriores si me muestran los valores correctos", como dices.  Quiere decir que el código que esta dentro se ejecutará cuando haya respuesta.

Existen diversas formas sin embargo como estas empezando te recomiendo esta ya que es la mas fácil sabiendo que también estas iniciando y no te será difícil implementarla.
ESTO SOLO VA A FUNCIONAR SI OBTIENES LOS DATOS EN UN TU ACTIVITY Y LOS USAS EN UN FRAGMENTO, SI LOS USAS EN LA MISMA ACTIVITY NO ABRA TIEMPO PARA QUE LOS DATOS SE OBTENGAN Y TE SALDRA EL MISMO ERROR.

El codigo esta en Kotlin, pero es muy simple.

```
//CREA UNA CLASE dentro de ella un companion object    
class Varss {   
        companion object{
        
        //Podras utilizar la variable en cualquier fragmento o activity 

        var nombre:String = ""
         
        //LA tuya seria algo asi
        ArrayList<String> usuariosLista = new ArrayList<>();

   }
}
```

Cambia

```
usuariosLista.add(nombreDeUsuario);
```

Por

```
Varss.usuariosLista.add(nombreDeUsuario);
```

**Si deseas usar la variables en la misma activity podrías crear una función dentro de**

```
db.collection("usuarios")
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>()
```

Así cuando ya se hallan obtenido los datos se actualizarían sin provocar el error.
Por ejemplos si quieres  asignar el dato obtenido a un textView.

fun actualizardato() {

```
 textView.text = Varss.usuariosLista.get(0)  //agrega .toString() si tiene algun error
```

}

Agregala dentro, y cuando los datos se halla obtenido se actualizara.

Espero que sea útil, si tienes mas dudas me encantaría ayudarte en lo que pueda.

Comment: Graciass!! Me ha funcionado.